# Read-in file and compare each element

Tags: java, string, class, text, compiler-errors

I have two given files in which each line is composed by four elements which are seperated by ','. I want to read-in both files in order to compare the lines of both, but I also want to list them. Most lines in both files are identical, but there are also lines present just in one of both files or they have one element different. My class of the elements is the following one:

```
public class Student {
    public String name;
    public Student (String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public static String[] toString(String name)
    {
        String s1 = ""; String s2 = ""; String s3 = ""; String s4 = "";
        int position = 0;
        for(int i = 0; name.charAt(i) != name.length(); i++)
        {
            if (name.charAt(i) == ',') {++position; continue;}
            if (position == 0) s1 += name.charAt(i);
            if (position == 1) s2 += name.charAt(i);
            if (position == 2) s3 += name.charAt(i);
            if (position == 3) s4 += name.charAt(i);
        }
        String[] s = new String[4];
        return s;
    }
}
```

I also have a CSVReader, which I haven't finished, I think:

```
public class CSVReader {

    /**
     * This method reads in a *.csv file and saves every entry as elements 
     * from a twodimensional array.
     *
     * @param filename track to the file Pfad zur Datei, example 
     * ".Root/test/echo.csv"
     * @return {@code String[][] s}  where {@code s[i][j]}
     * is the j-th value in the i-th line
     */
    public String[][] readCSV(String filename) {
        ArrayList<String[]> result = new ArrayList<>();

        BufferedReader br = null;
        String line = "";
        String cvsSplitBy = ",";
        StringBuilder  stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                result.add(line.split(cvsSplitBy));
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (br != null) {
                try {
                    br.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return result.toArray(new String[result.size()][]);
    }
}
```

My problem is how to use the CSVReader in the main class:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        /**
         * Read in "./Root/files/echo.csv" und "./Root/files/file1.csv"
         * and output the correspondent warning on System.out
         */
        String file1 = new String("");
        String echo = "";
        file1 = CSVReader("./Root/files/file1.csv"); /*cannot find 
        symbol */
        echo = CSVReader("./Root/files/echo.csv"); // same error
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You can make `readCSV()` `static` and do: `String[][] file1 = CSVReader.readCSV("./Root/files/file1.csv");`

Comment: And how would be the last element be called for the for-loop I want to do, to compare both files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the `readCsv` method in the `CSVReader` class static so you can call it anywhere:

```
public static String[][] readCSV(String filename)
```

Now you can call `CSVReader.readCsv`:

```
file1 = CSVReader.readCsv("./Root/files/file1.csv");
echo = CSVReader.readCsv("./Root/files/echo.csv");
```

Answer (score 0):

In this line
`file1 = CSVReader("./Root/files/file1.csv"); /*cannot find symbol */`
Java compailer "seys" you that cannot resolve what is `CSVReader`.
Your syntax is like you tray to call a function.

One solution is this code snipet

```
CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader();
file1 = csvReader.readCsv("./Root/files/file1.csv");
echo = csvReader.readCsv("./Root/files/echo.csv");
```

Note: `csvReader` is a variable.

The another solution is to add static modifier to `readCsv` method. In tat case code will look like this (no the constructor call)

```
file1 = CSVReader.readCsv("./Root/files/file1.csv");
echo = CSVReader.readCsv("./Root/files/echo.csv");
```

Comment: I see that the output is not what I want. How can I output every line of my file separetedly by using the Student class?

Comment: Yes, but I need to know how, beause there are things I don't know in Java.

Comment: Your question was "My problem is how to use the CSVReader in the main class...". So, I tried to answer on that. If something does work properly, then create another question. 
"... beause there are things I don't know in Java."
Here is SO community to help you. Good luck.

Comment: Ah, I see, the problem is once the CSVReader itself, then also the read-in in the main class. But still, I want it line by line, not the whole file at once.